# Javascript Reference error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to call a javascript function on keydown but I have an error:

```js
/* Calling the javascript file */
$(document).ready(function() {
  item_set();
});

/* custom.js */
function item_set(){
 $(document).ready(function() {
  function check(idname) { 
          // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
      var e=document.getElementById(idname);
          if (jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
               // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
              (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
               // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
              (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                   // let it happen, don't do anything
                   return;
          }
          // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
          if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      };
   };
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item_cost" id="item_cost" class="form-control" onkeydown="check(item_cost)" />
```

The error in console is:

> ReferenceError: check is not defined

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Have you added the script in the same file as html, or if not have you provided the path of the JS file?

Comment: The script is in a different file but I call it with a function! I'm sure about this because I have more functions over there and they are working.

Comment: tell me what exactly you need to do. e=document.getElementById(idname); --> where is this Id?

Comment: Are you calling check() somewhere? Also any reason you're going about it this way? Why not just script include the file? Or try implementing an ES6 module or use require.js?

Comment: Yes I'm calling in HTML Page... Above there is the code <input .... > The id is "item_cost"

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you need to reference the custom script in your calling file.

```
<script src="custom.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    item_set(); //now you have access to this function
  });
</script>
```

Side note: I like putting all of my scripts at the end of the `<body>`, that way you dont have to bother with `$(document).ready()`

```
...
<body>
  ...
  html
  and
  stuff
  ...
  <script src="custom.js"></script>
  <script>
    item_set();
  </script>
</body>
```